# What makes values appear in the result set again and how were their names replaced with NULL values?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, left-join, correlated-subquery

Here is the link to the entity-relationship diagram of the database.

https://ibb.co/knPSFe

Here is the statement I'm interested in. It is taken from the book called "Alan Beaulieu Learning_SQL". It can be found on page 177 in case you want to read about it there. The topic of this query is "Subqueries as Expression Generators".

[image]

As you can see the result set includes the three "NULL" rows.They are thought to be sorted out by the WHERE clause of the first subquery:

```
AND p.product_type_cd = 'ACCOUNT'
```

Here is an extract from the book:

> The reason for the extra three rows in the result set is that the previous version of the query included the filter condition `p.product_type_cd = 'ACCOUNT'`. That filter eliminated rows with product types of INSURANCE and LOAN, such as small business loans.
>
> Since this version of the query doesn’t include a join to the product table, there is no way to include the filter condition in the main query. The correlated subquery against the product table does include this filter, but the only effect is to leave the product name
>   null.

This is "the previous version of the query":

[image]

> The correlated subquery against the product table does include this filter, but the only effect is to leave the product name null.

**How does it do it? What is the order of evaluation?**

The query

[image]

returns the first column "product" with INSURANCE and LOAN products types sorted out. **What makes them appear in the result set again and how were their names replaced with NULL values?**

Comment: Please don't post SQL queries as screenshots (because that makes it impossible to just copy + run them). Also, please add the data from the referenced tables to turn your question into a [MCVE].

Comment: Or see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: What have you learned about the (conceptual) order of evaluation? What you *think* the steps are that lead to the result in each example? Where do your expectations differ? PS Please use text for the text of ERDs; then if it's helpful also give the ERD; but here it's not; plus this ERD has tons of irrelevant stuff. Please reorder your presentation to avoid jumping around. Please make your two questions into one question. Refer to things clearly; use enough words & sentences to be clear. PS When you say "sorted out" do you mean "filtered out"?

Answer (score 0):

The order of the results is the same for both queries.
What is mainly different in this scenario is that they used INNER JOIN in the second query and not in the first one.

INNER JOIN force the query to be executed ONLY when there are results DIFFERENT THAN NULL.

I believe that for it to display the same results, it would be just necessary to change from INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN.